# How to reference a dataframe and a series within a tuple within a list for my function

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to call a function on a dataframe and a series that is stored within tuple within a list.  I would then like to store the results as a dataframe within a list.  I feel like I am close but not close enough!

Currently I have:

- A list called makes_train_test_sets that contains:
- 11 tuples of size 4 for each VehicleMake in my dataset, containing:
- 2 dataframes (X test data, X train data) and 2 Series (y test data and y train data)

I then need to run a regression function using X_train and Y_train from each tuple but I am having trouble calling them.

The error I am receiving at the moment is: "cannot copy sequence with size 19474 to array axis with dimension 23"

I suspect because I am referring to column instead of the index?

I called one of the Series within the tuple to see what would happen and it has created another list of series, but I just need to access the series and the dataframe for my functions down the line:

```
[t[2] for t in makes_train_test_sets]
```

So, for example, my original dataset looked like this (there are many more rows and many more VehicleMakes):

```
converted   avgrating   sortorder   price   VehicleMake
0   4.90    2   34800.84    Subaru
0   4.90    4   36500.53    Subaru
0   4.80    2   30000.20    Toyota
0   5.00    3   22600.94    Toyota
0   4.70    8   30500.69    Toyota
0   5.00    9   31400.94    Toyota
0   4.70    13  31200.44    Toyota
0   4.50    14  29800.44    Toyota
0   0.00    17  29900.14    Toyota
0   0.00    18  32003.45    Toyota
```

Which needs to get split into VehicleMake and training and test data within each VehcileMake:

```
def split_train_test(df):
    # Determine dependant variable
    #X = df.iloc[:,1:]
    X = df.drop(columns = ['Converted', 'VehicleMake'])
    y = df['Converted']
    # Split data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = skl.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

By applying the above function to the below to split into VehicleMake (works fine):

```
makers_dataframes = []
for maker in df['VehicleMake'].unique():
    makers_dataframes.append(df.loc[df['VehicleMake'] == maker])

makes_train_test_sets = [
    split_train_test(maker_df) for maker_df in makers_dataframes
]
```

So now my data is a list:
[makes_train_test_sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cM1S.png)

Which has tuples for each VehicleMake:
[tuples within makes_train_test_sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKEWy.png)

And each tuple has 2 dataframes and 2 series which contains the data I need to get to:
[dataframes and series I want to get to within tuples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy6IR.png)

So I can apply this function:

```
def regression_logit(y_train, X_train):
    logit_model = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train.astype(float))
    result = logit_model.fit(method = 'bfgs')
    # Create data frame with variable outcomes from regression
    LRresult = (result.summary2().tables[1])
    return LRresult
```

This is how I am attempting to get to the data:

```
make_results = [
    regression_logit([t[2] for t in makes_train_test_sets], [t[0] for t in makes_train_test_sets]))
]
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide a full working example.

Comment: Thanks @marcotama I have tried to add a little data and pictures of what I need...is that more descriptive?

Comment: Just curious, is there a specific reason your not using sklearn?

Comment: Because sklearn LogisticRegression does not have a built in method to calculate p-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think, that both arguments in your function `regression_logit(y_train, X_train)` are meant to be arrays. However you put lists to this function while defining `make_results`.

I would suggest to iterate over items in tuples and append results to `make_results` list.

```
make_results = []
for y_train, X_train in zip([t[2] for t in makes_train_test_sets], 
                            [t[0] for t in makes_train_test_sets]):
    make_results.append(regression_logit(y_train, X_train))
```